# How can I revert my local git repository to the state it has on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I'm using Git and want to get rid of all my current changes and make my files look exactly like they do in my repo on GitHub. How do I do this?

I've been searching around and found things but I want to be careful not to mess anything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start fresh with what is on github, the simplest route is to just make a new clone.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this in a new directory first to make sure that you are certain of what it does. If you have a HEAD (possibly from a previous commit), you can use:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This dumps your current changes and move back to where you last committed (i.e. where you last left off).

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5):

See: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This will help you get through.